# Get MS Touch Mouse "expose style" gesture without mouse

Tags: windows-7

The MS touch mouse has a gesture to bring up an expose style task switcher to show all open windows.

Is this a built in feature of Windows 7, and can I use it from a keyboard shortcut?

Comment: Does it look the same as Alt+Tab, or Win+Tab?

Comment: Watched the video, no it isn't. It's very similar to Mac's Expose

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://gizmodo.com/5731028/this-is-a-real-magic-mouse-for-windows

> An Expose ripoff is the one thing that's been missing from Windows 7's Aero interface, but right now it's only part of the Intellimouse software package that comes with the Touch Mouse.

There is something you can install that does similar things to Expose, http://insentient.net/ and here is a list of expose clones http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expos%C3%A9_clone#For_Windows

Comment: This isn't exactly true that Intellipoint is the only game in town - for one thing, Logitech Setpoint has similar functionality for certain mice.

Comment: The more you know! Thanks, I wasn't aware of that.